# Do java monitoring tools such as jconsole force garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I was using jconsole to monitor my java application and one thing I have observed is the Perform GC button always seems to trigger garbage collection and reduce the memory been used by the app.

Jconsole is using JMX to connect to the app. I assume that it must have access to the Mbean and be able to trigger GC but going through the docs - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/j2se/1.5.0/jcp/beta1/apidiffs/java/lang/management/MemoryMBean.html#gc() , it seems gc() of Mbean is equivalent to System.gc() which is just a hint for GC

Do monitoring apps have some mechanism to force GC for an app ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: These tools do not have more authority than `System.gc()`. You're just using a JVM, that respects that hint.

Comment: If you dump heap with Jconsole or other tool, side effect of heap dump would be a full gc.
Same for class histogram which could be initiate with jcmd and corresponding MBean.